# Python Image.open() is not showing the image

Tags: image, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to place an image over a canvas, but I cannot seem to get the image to show. I was able to get the image to show using photoimage() however it lacks the ability to resize. Am I missing something?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


canvas_width = 285
canvas_height =420

master = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()

img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\kraak\Desktop\PyCharm Community Editionz 2017.1.2\2.png")

img.show()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Different packages use different data structures to store things, so a PIL `Image` isn't the same as a tkinter `image`.

Instead, stick with tkinter, and [use subsample to resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316328/cannot-resize-image-with-tkinter), as [noted in the docs](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.PhotoImage-class.html).