# Too early to create image at NewWindow

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I want to display the image in a new window, but I get an error.

This is my error code

```
photo = PhotoImage(file='img/dog')
File "C:\Users\Hyojae\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3542, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "C:\Users\Hyojae\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3486, in __init__
raise RuntimeError('Too early to create image')
RuntimeError: Too early to create image
```

And this is my code sample.

I would appreciate your help.

```
from tkinter import *

def messageWindow():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry('300x200')

    root.destroy()


    photo2 = PhotoImage(file="img/dog1.gif")
    label1 = Label(win, image=photo2)
    label1.grid(row=6)

    Button(win, text='OK', command=win.destroy).grid(row = 5, columnspan = 2)

    win.mainloop()

root = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file="img/dog2.gif")
label1 = Label(root, image=photo)
label1.pack()


Button(root, text='Bring up Message', command=messageWindow).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try moving the line `root.destroy()` before `win = Tk()` to avoid multiple instances of `Tk()` which may cause problems.

Comment: Or you can specify the `Tk` instance to be used when initiating the `PhotoImage` instance: `photo2 = PhotoImage(file="img/dog1.gif", master=win)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting such area because you call `root.destroy` before the image is loaded to the window.Also you can not use two `TK` instance you have to use [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) check the link to understand better.

Aside that to display image in `toplevel` you need to create reference for it so it will not be garbage collected [Display image in Toplevel window](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)
which i did this way `label1.image = sub`.

I also use `image subsample` to demonstrate how to resize image `sub = photo2.subsample(5, 5)` check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316328/cannot-resize-image-with-tkinter) to read about it

```
from tkinter import *

def messageWindow():
    win = Toplevel()
    win.geometry('300x200')

    root.withdraw() # THIS HIDE THE WINDOW


    photo2 = PhotoImage(file="img/dog1.gif")
    sub = photo2.subsample(5, 5)
    label1 = Label(win, image=sub)
    label1.image = sub
    label1.grid(row=6)

    Button(win, text='OK', command=win.destroy).grid(row = 5, columnspan = 2)



root = Tk()


photo = PhotoImage(file="img/dog1.gif")
sub1 = photo.subsample(3,3)
label1 = Label(root, image=sub1)
label1.pack()


B = Button(root, text='Bring up Message', command=messageWindow)
B.place(x=200, y=300)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
But I have to destroy the original window.

Comment: you cant destroy the `root` window whilst toplevel is preserved because it is slave to the window to do that you have to use `wihtdraw` function.

Comment: @이효재 If solves your problem make sure you tick as a reference for future coders.